# How can I limit data usage depending on whether the screen is on, or off/locked?

Tags: applications, data-connection, background-data

How can I limit data usage depending on whether the screen is on, or off/locked? For example, when the screen is off, data can only be sent and received at a reduced rate. Or, when the screen is off, data connectivity is reduced to 2G. I want to leave data on, but I don't want to let it chew through all of it.

I am aware of the data saver option, but it doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). I've rephrased it slightly to match this site's rules as well as your intention.

Comment: This literally sounds like what JuiceDefender does... One of the few "battery saver" apps I would actually recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could  try [CleverConnectivity No Ads](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gyagapen.cleverconnectivitynoads&hl=en).

**How it works**

CleverConnectivity  will automatically turn on and off connectivity
 (data/wifi/sync) while screen is OFF.

> For example if the user chooses below configuration:
>   *Time On: 2min*
>   *Time On Next Check: 1min* *Time Off: 10m* *Usage check Interval: 3s*
>
> - Once the screen is OFF, CleverConnectivity will keep connectivity alive for 2min. Then it will check if data is used during a period of
>     3s.
> - If data is used, connectivity will be kept for 1 minute (Time On Next Check).
> - If data is NOT used, connectivity will be deactivated for 10min. After this, the connectivity will be re-activated and Time On will
>     kick in.
> - Once screen is ON, connectivity will be automatically re-enabled.

- With a custom ROM there is also an option to keep conneectivity to 2G only whilst screen is off.

[image]

*NB (from author): This app is not yet fully compatible with Android Lollipop 5+ as Google has restricted the access to the method to toggle mobile data programatically*

Answer (score 0):

Use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) app which can disable the internet connection automatically when the screen is off. Configure the app as below:

Profile: **Screen Off**

Context: (Event) **Screen off**

**Task:**

```
Clear variable %SCREENSTATE
Stop if %POWER ~ ON
Disable "Mobile Data" (With "Keep MMS" if you want)
Disable "Auto-SYNC"
```

Set Profile's Task Priority to 6